# C macro to expose property of ivar in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macros

In my project, I usually have a composite object (GameObject) that needs to expose a few properties of an ivar into the GameObject's interface. For example, a GameObject has a Sprite with a 'position' property, and I want to use the Sprite's position as a property of the GameObject. This is easy enough with:

```
// GameObject.h
@interface GameObject : NSObject
@property CGPoint position;
...
@end

// GameObject.m
@interface GameObject ()
@property Sprite* sprite;   // private property
@end 

@implementation
- (CGPoint)position { return sprite.position; };
- (void)setPosition:(CGPoint)p { sprite.position = p; };
...
```

As a side project, I have been looking at generating the getter/setter with a C macro. Ideally I would be able to do:

```
@implementation
EXPOSE_SUBCOMPONENT_PROPERTY(subcomponent,propertyName,propertyType);
...
```

My latest failed attempt is:

```
#define EXPOSE_SUBCOMPONENT_PROPERTY(sub,property,type) \
- (type)property { id x = sub; return x.##property;} \
- (void)setProperty:(type)set_val { id x = sub; x.##property = set_val; } \
```

Any macro wizards out there able to help out?
Secondly, is there a way to not need to supply the type of the property to the macro?

Comment: Have you looked into `@synthesize`

Comment: I'm not sure you completely read my question. I want a property(position) of a ivar(sprite) to be a property of the enclosing object(gameObject)- use gameObject.position instead of gameObject.sprite.position. If '@synthesize' was more magical, I would be able to do '@synthesize position = sprite.position;'

Comment: you could always use bindings + KVO...

Comment: The point is that I don't want to expose the rest of the sprite's properties in my public interface. I'm not binding it to anything, I just need access. For example, somewhere else would be 'if (gameObject.position.x > someX) { ...'

Comment: Ok, let me whip something up, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Also, is C++ on the table? Templates could make this simpler...

Comment: No, C++ + obj-c gives me the heeby jeebies.

Comment: I hear you, it does to me too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better solution. The trick was understanding how symbols are split up, to properly use '##'. Also, had to add a macro for the property declaration to customize the getter/setter names, which gets around the issue of capitalizing the name of the property. Not a big deal for me, helps me remember its a special property. The only downsize I can think of is they won't be KVO compliant because of the custom name.

I renamed the macros to make them easier to remember (they substitute for a @property and @synthesize respectively), and rearranged the argument order to mirror a property.

```
#define PROPERTY_OF_IVAR(prop_type,ivar,prop_name) \
    @property (setter=set_##prop_name:, getter=get_##prop_name) prop_type prop_name \

#define SYNTHESIZE_IVAR_PROPERTY(prop_type,ivar,prop_name) \
    - (prop_type)get_##prop_name { return ivar.prop_name;} \
    - (void)set_##prop_name:(prop_type)set_val { ivar.prop_name = set_val; } \
```

Another version, makes @property declarations more natural, and has the added bonus of being able to a property at any depth (rather than just ivar properties, you can reach down to ivar.property.another_property.indefinitely). You can also set the name of the property to be different from its name in the composed object.

```
// prop_type - type of property that will be exposed
// prop_name - name of property in composing object
#define PROPERTY_OF_IVAR(prop_type, prop_name) \
    (setter=set_##prop_name:, getter=get_##prop_name) prop_type prop_name \

// prop_type - type of property that will be exposed
// prop_path - path to the property you want
// prop_name - must match PROPERTY_OF_IVAR (above)
#define SYNTHESIZE_IVAR_PROPERTY(prop_type, prop_path,prop_name) \
    - (prop_type)get_##prop_name { return prop_path;} \
    - (void)set_##prop_name:(prop_type)set_val { prop_path = set_val; } \
```

Example use:

```
// foo.h
@interface
@property PROPERTY_OF_IVAR(CGPoint, position);
...

// foo.m
@implementation
SYNTHESIZE_IVAR_PROPERTY(CGPoint, sprite.position, position);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright you asked for it, but brace yourself, it gets UGLY fast:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

#define EXPOSE_SUBCOMPONENT_PROPERTY(selfClass, sub, property) \

static typeof([[selfClass new] property]) ___get##property(id self, SEL _cmd)\
{\
return ((selfClass *)self)->sub.property;\
}\
static void ___set##property(id self, SEL _cmd, ...)\
{\
selfClass *selfCasted = (selfClass *) self; \
va_list args; va_start(args, _cmd); \
typeof(selfCasted.property) _val = va_arg(args, typeof (selfCasted.property));\
selfCasted->sub.property = _val;\
}\
__attribute__((constructor)) \
static void __init##__property() \
{\
Class cls = [selfClass class];\
class_addMethod(cls, @selector(property), (IMP) ___get##property, "");\
/* for capitalization */ \
char selAsStr[sizeof(#property) + 4] = "set";\
strcat(selAsStr, #property ":");\
selAsStr[3] = toupper(selAsStr[3]);\
class_addMethod(cls, sel_registerName(selAsStr), (IMP) ___set##property, "");\
}\
```

You don't need to get the return type anymore, but you have to send the class type to the method.

GCC must be used for this as extensive use of extensions are used, alternatively, you could use C++ 11, but I wouldn't recommend it.

I wouldn't really recommend using this, but if you want something cool to mess around with, go ahead and try it!